# Complex infinity when using Fullsimplify to sum

Tags: summation

I am trying to simply and speed up a sum using Fullsimplify, when I try the simplified expression with a simple example, it comes up with Complex infinity. How do the Fullsimplify itself give an expression like that?

```
ClearAll[p, p1, n, A, v];

p[n_, A_, v_, x_] := 
  Sum[Sum[Binomial[n - 1, n - j]*v^(j - 1)*
     Binomial[n - j, n - i]*(1 - x)^(n - i)*(x - v)^(i - j)*
     A/(n - i + 1), {j, i}], {i, n - A}];

Sum[Sum[Binomial[n - 1, n - j]*v^(j - 1)*
    Binomial[n - j, n - i]*(1 - x)^(n - i)*(x - v)^(i - j)*
    A/(n - i + 1), {j, i}], {i, n - A}] // FullSimplify

p1[n_, A_, x_] := (1 - x)^
   n ((1/(1 - x))^n/(
     n - n x) - ((x/(-1 + x))^(1 - A + n)
       Gamma[-A] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, -A, 1 - A + n, 
       x/(-1 + x)])/(x Gamma[1 - n]));

p1[4,2,x]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `Limit`

```
ClearAll[p,p1,n,A,v,x];
p[n_,A_,v_,x_]:=Sum[Sum[Binomial[n-1,n-j]*v^(j-1)*Binomial[n-j,n-i]*(1-x)^(n-i)*(x-v)^(i-j)*A/(n-i+1),{j,i}],{i,n-A}];
simplifiedExpr=FullSimplify[p[n,A,v,x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
p1[nValue_,AValue_,xValue_]:=Limit[simplifiedExpr,n->nValue]/.A->AValue/.x->xValue

p1[4,2,x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It works, but the result is different from the original expression, Expand[p[4,2,v,x]//Fullsimplify] gives 1/2+x/2-5*x^2/2+3*x^3/2, am I miss anything?

Comment: @Lomath I looked more into it. I do not know why `Expand[p[4,2,v,x]//Fullsimplify` gives different result. But if you do  `Series[ p1[4,2,x],{x,0,6}]` it now becomes similar  in the first few terms at least to what your command gives. anyway, maybe there is something else going on. But my point in this answer is to avoid the 1/0 you had by taking the limit.  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVH83.png)

Comment: Thanks! It seems that under the command "Limit", the second terms goes to 0, remaining the first term A/(n-nx).

Comment: Maybe the problem is about Gamma[-A]/Gamma[1-n] in the second terms, when Gamma[] comes up with a negative parameter, it gives ComplexInfinity, but I do not know why FullSimplify gives such expression.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Assuming` is one way to this problem. As we can see, without Assuming, The `FullSimplify` gives:
[image]

When A>0 and n>1, there will be Gamma[] with a negative parameter, which gives ComplexInfinity.

Given that we want n,A are positive intergers,we use `Assuming`:

```
Assuming[Element[n, PositiveIntegers] && Element[A, PositiveIntegers],
  FullSimplify[
  Sum[Sum[Binomial[n - 1, n - j]*v^(j - 1)*
     Binomial[n - j, n - i]*(1 - x)^(n - i)*(x - v)^(i - j)*
     A/(n - i + 1), {j, i}], {i, n - A}]]]
```

It will give:
[image]

That's what I want, an expression that is useful for positive intergers n,A.